# Tail parameter of transformed data

Tags: quantiles, fat-tails

Suppose I have a variable r that has a tail index $\alpha$. How can I know the new tail index if I transform the data, for example using $r^2$ instead? I am using the Hill estimator to estimate the tail index but so fat I can't see a relationship between the parameters when I transform the data.